# bash - unable to replace text with special symbols and spaces

Tags: bash

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
authConfig="./auth/phinx.php"
read -p "Enter MySQL Auth database name: " databaseName
databaseSearch="'name' => 'development_db'"
replaceDatabase="'name' => '$databaseName'"

if [[  $databaseName != "" ]]; then
sed -i -e "s/$databaseSearch/$replaceDatabase/g" $authConfig
fi
```

Here is the content of phinx.php:

```
<?php

return
[
    'paths' => [
        'migrations' => '%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/db/migrations',
        'seeds' => '%%PHINX_CONFIG_DIR%%/db/seeds'
    ],
    'environments' => [
        'default_migration_table' => 'phinxlog',
        'default_environment' => 'development',
        'production' => [
            'adapter' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'name' => 'production_db',
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => '',
            'port' => '3306',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'development' => [
            'adapter' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'name' => 'development_db',
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => '',
            'port' => '3306',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'testing' => [
            'adapter' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'name' => 'testing_db',
            'user' => 'root',
            'pass' => '',
            'port' => '3306',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]
    ],
    'version_order' => 'creation'
];
```

It looks like `sed` can't find the string. Why is that and where is my mistake?

Comment: FWIW, "works for me"!  The code looks OK to me too.  Sorry.

Comment: did you check the whitespace characters match?

Comment: Maybe try `[[:space:]]\+` instead of the spaces?

Comment: Works for me on Linux Mint 20.  Could you have DOS end of line characters maybe?  `dos2unix ./auth/phinx.php`